# Problem to retrieve data from my database in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a problem when I try to read a data from my database in WordPress and then print it on the screen, but nothing appears. Here is my code:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$table = $wpdb::query('SELECT * FROM stock_disponible');
$donne = $table::fetch();
echo $donne['stocks'];
?>
```

`stock_disponible` is the table from were I want to take the first entries and display the value stored in the column `stocks`.

If someone can tell me what I don't do correctly to display my value on the screen or how I can access the database with PHP.

Comment: $donne['stocks']

Comment: _"I have a problem"_ is not useful. Tell us what the problem is. What are you expecting to get? What are you actually getting? What error messages do you see? Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

You should try below code

```
<?php 
global $wpdb;
$postdata = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM stock_disponible ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;" ) );
echo "<pre>";print_r($postdata);exit;
?>
```

Comment: On StackOverflow, and explanation of how proposed works and why it solves the described problem is preferred over "Try this.". The latter gives an impression of a shot in the dark. Or worse, a clarification question, which should better be done as a comment. You do have the commenting privilege you know.